# WooCommerce bug iPhone 7 plus iOS 10.3.*

Tags: iphone, wordpress, svg, woocommerce, ios10.3

I am developing a website (WordPress + WooCommerce). When I tested the website on mobile (iPhone7+ with iOS 10.3), I found two bugs.

1. custom loading symbol can't work (use svg with animation).
2. when add a item into cart. It show 2 items and can't add more items into cart as well.

The website works all devices except iPhone with IOS 10.3. I also test on Iphone6 with version 10.2 and it works normally, then the phone is updated to 10.3 for testing, it got same problems. Therefore, I guess that the problem is from iOS.

Does anyone test WooCommerce website on iPhone with iOS 10.3?

Comment: Can you please tell me WP and WC version

Comment: I am using version 4.7.5 for WP and 2.6.14 for WC

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.